# Redefining \chapter*, \section* and \subsection*

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, report

My problem is this one: I'm creating a LaTeX template for reports, my goal is to make a `.tex` file that is the simplest possible. I use a `.cls` file, where I'd like to redefine `\chapter*` (and so on), but not `\chapter`. I didn't find a way to do this precisely, so I ask my question here.

What I want to do is, to keep the `\chapter*`, `\section*` and `\subsection*` in the Table of Contents, plus keeping the `\chapter*` name in the headings.

For now, each time I want to call

```
\chapter*{A random Chapter}
```

I have to call

```
\chapter*{A random Chapter}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}
{A random Chapter}\markboth{A random Chapter}{A random Chapter}
```

Which is not really convenient, in the sight of a template.

Does anyone what's the best solution to redefine them in a separate .cls file?

Thank you for your help!

PS: I'm quite new in LaTeX, I didn't know what tags to put on that topic, but I can add them by editing this post as soon as I know :)

Comment: With `scrbook` (or any KOMA-Script class) you have `\addchap{..}` which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Or use a very buggy package that tries to implement a bit of KOMA-functionality for the standard classes [unnumeredtotoc](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc).

Comment: You should show us the `.cls` file first. Most likely it's an offspring of `book` or something like that. Either use `unnumberedtotoc` or `xpatch` to patch the starred commands.

Comment: The `titlesec` package and its siblings `titletoc` and `titleps` packages can do that easily, since it defines a `numberless` key for formatting/spacing section-like structures.

Comment: Is your class based on one of the standard ones (`book`, `report`)?

Comment: If you tell us why you would want that we may be able to suggest better approaches...your request seems a bit strange as you put it...it's odd to have such disuniformity in chapter titles. Maybe you are looking for `\frontmatter`?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to suppress numbering globally is issuing:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

In that case you can just use the unstarred versions, they would be unnumbered but appear in the toc.

For more advanced configurations I would advise you to use the `titlesec` package.

Comment: This would suppress all numbers, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes it would, but from the question it was not clear if he needed both numbered and unnumbered versions. I nevertheless thought the secnumdepth thing could be useful to know

Comment: It is, in fact. And you're right. As long there is not more information, it's justified to assume that no sectioning numbers should be shown at all